# How do I mask a pandas column, based on values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, nan

I have a pandas dataframe (stored in excel) with timeseries for some groups.
I want to make a line plot of time series for those groups. I can't wrap my head around masking plots in pyplot. I need the plots to be masked (a gap in the plot) during winter months.

My starting point was this page here:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/masked_demo.html

I saw the documentation for pandas mask and where functions.
I also saw the numpy.ma.masked_where function documentation.

I could use the pandas.mask function - but only for one column. I can't figure out a way to use ['Months'] column to mask my ['Values'] column.

I tried exporting both columns to numpy using pandas.as_matrix(). Then I masked the ['Values'] using numpy.ma.masked_where. However when I tried to put it back into pandas dataframe it's unmasking, and the values are still there.

```
#Lets say I have a dataframe called df. 
#It has following columns [['Date','Month', 'Values', 'GroupName']]

#This works, and the values seem to be masked, because they print as --
months = df['Month'].as_matrix()
values = df['Values'].as_matrix()
masked = np.ma.masked_where(months in ['5','6','7','8','9'], values)

#However this here unmasks the values =(
df['MaskedValues'] = masked

#This is how I do the plotting - I plot values from each group onto one plot

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#Loops over groups and adds them to the plot
for key, group in df.groupby(['GroupName']):
    ax = group.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x='Date', y='MaskedValues', label=key, figsize=(40,15), fontsize=30, color='black')
```

My end goal is to obtain a line plot, where the lines outside of summer months are erased. I want there to be a gap in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need in your case

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40, 15))
w = (10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4)
for key, group in df.groupby(['GroupName']):
    group.mask(df.Month.isin(w)).plot(ax=ax, x='Date', y='Values', label=key, fontsize=30, color='black')
```

*Note that you don't need to assign the ax every iteration and figsize should be placed into subplots.*

---

I'll give you an mcve here, which is some sinusodial data over two years:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = pd.date_range('1.1.2000', '31.12.2001')
data = np.sin(np.arange(len(t.day))/10)
```

In the according dataframe, an additional column `month` is added, which will be used for masking:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': data, 'month': t.month}, index=t)
```

(*In my example winter ends already after march... :)*)

```
w = (10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3)
```

Then you can plot all values except those, where `month` is in `w` by:

```
df.value.mask(df.month.isin(w)).plot()
plt.show()
```